# How to conditionally join a table function in Oracle SQL, which has a primary table row column as an argument, without excessive function calls?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following issue:
Every row in my base table have a flag column ('flg' in the listing below) and an function argument column ('arg'). If in a row #N the flag is 'Y', then function has to be called; after, it shall return, let's say, a column (actually a bunch of them, but i'll simplify as much as i can). And finally, the row #N should transform into a sub-table - full join of a row #N and the column, returned by the function.
If the flag is 'N' then a result for the row #N shall be as the row itself plus NULL in that "function return column".

So here's an example:

```
create or replace package SIEBEL.TEST_PACKAGE as
    type ret_type is table of number;
    function testFunc(inp number)
    return ret_type
    pipelined;
end TEST_PACKAGE;
/
create or replace package body SIEBEL.TEST_PACKAGE is
    function testFunc(inp number)
    return ret_type
    pipelined
    is
    i number;
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('Function call, arg = ' || to_char(inp));
        if (inp is null OR inp = 0) then
            pipe row (null);
        else
            for i in 1..inp loop
                 pipe row (i);
            end loop;
        end if;
    end testFunc;
end TEST_PACKAGE;
/
with base_table as
(
    select 'Shall invoke' col0, 'Y' flg, '2' arg from dual
    union
    select 'Shall not invoke' col0, 'N' flg, '0' arg from dual
)
select * from base_table t0, table(siebel.test_package.testFunc(t0.arg)) t1;
```

It will return what i actually want:

```
COL0              | FLG | ARG | COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------
Shall invoke      |  Y  |  2  |      1
Shall invoke      |  Y  |  2  |      2
Shall not invoke  |  N  |  0  |
```

The thing is, even for the 'N' flag the function is still called - the database output will show

```
Function call, arg = 2
Function call, arg = 0
```

If a real world i have hundreds of records with 'Y' flag, ~100K with 'N'. Alse my actual function is much more complicated and have a lot of stuff in its namespace, so every function call is crucial in terms of perfomance.

What i do want is the database output for the example:

```
Function call, arg = 2
```

I could achieve it with

```
with base_table as
    (
        select 'Shall invoke' col0, 'Y' flg, '2' arg from dual
        union
        select 'Shall not invoke' col0, 'N' flg, '0' arg from dual
    )
select t.*, t1.column_value
    from base_table t, table(SIEBEL.TEST_PACKAGE.testFunc(t.arg)) t1
    where t.flg = 'Y'
union all
select t.*, null as column_value
    from base_table t 
    where t.flg = 'N';
```

but then all indexes became useless - every 'order by' instruction will take alot to complete.

Please, help me to achieve the desired behaviour of function calls and still to save the primal rows order.

Feel free to ask me if anything is not clear.

Best Regards,
Alexey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For flag = "N" the function is not called if you conditionally join

```
set serveroutput on
with base_table as
(
    select 'Shall invoke' col0, 'Y' flg, '2' arg from dual
    union
    select 'Shall not invoke' col0, 'N' flg, '0' arg from dual
)
select * from base_table t0
left join table( test_package.testFunc(t0.arg) ) t1 on (t0.flg = 'Y');
```

Script Output

```
Package created.
Package body created.

COL0             FLG ARG COLUMN_VALUE
---------------- --- --- ------------
Shall invoke     Y   2              1
Shall invoke     Y   2              2
Shall not invoke N   0               

3 rows selected.
```

Server Output:

```
Function call, arg = 2
```

Comment: Yes, i can. Still, a) The function will be called even if the flag is 'N'. Every function call cost a lot of processing time (Prepare function call stack, change context etc). This is not what i want. b) I have to select 'Shall not invoke' rows too. 
Anyways, thanks for the reply

Comment: Got it. I made an edit. In the example you still get the "Shall not invoke" line and according to server output the function is called only once.

Comment: Thank you, good sir!
You'll laugh, but I've tried conditional joins, but, in difference from your solution, i've forgotten the 'left' statement :) That amateur mistake cost me alot of time, nerves, and the question at stackoverflow.
Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the function call for `flag = 'N'`, filter out the row.

Add `where flg='Y'` in the **filter predicate**.

For better performance, create an **index** on `flg` column.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> with base_table as
  2  (
  3      select 'Shall invoke' col0, 'Y' flg, '2' arg from dual
  4      union
  5      select 'Shall not invoke' col0, 'N' flg, '0' arg from dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM base_table t0, TABLE(test_package.testFunc(t0.arg)) t1
  8  where flg='Y';

COL0             F A COLUMN_VALUE
---------------- - - ------------
Shall invoke     Y 2            1
Shall invoke     Y 2            2

Function call, arg = 2
SQL>
```

**Edit**

To have the rows for `'flg='N'` also in the output, you could do an **OUTER JOIN**, no need of **UNION**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE table base_table AS
  2  select * from(
  3    ( SELECT 'Shall invoke' col0, 'Y' flg, '2' arg FROM dual
  4    UNION
  5    SELECT 'Shall not invoke' col0, 'N' flg, '0' arg FROM dual
  6    )
  7    );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM base_table t0
  3  LEFT JOIN TABLE( test_package.testFunc(t0.arg) ) t1
  4  ON (t0.flg = 'Y');

COL0             F A COLUMN_VALUE
---------------- - - ------------
Shall invoke     Y 2            1
Shall invoke     Y 2            2
Shall not invoke N 0

SQL>
```

You can check the **explain plan** to see how the function is called and how many times is it executed.

```
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT *
  3  FROM base_table t0
  4  LEFT JOIN TABLE( test_package.testFunc(t0.arg) ) t1
  5  ON (t0.flg = 'Y');

Explained.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2726614787

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                 | 16336 |   510K|    61   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER                  |                 | 16336 |   510K|    61   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | BASE_TABLE      |     2 |    38 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   VIEW                               | VW_LAT_D4FD8C38 |  8168 |   103K|    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    FILTER                            |                 |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |     COLLECTION ITERATOR PICKLER FETCH| TESTFUNC        |  8168 | 16336 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - filter("T0"."FLG"='Y')

17 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: The thing is, I have to select both 'Shall not invoke' and 'Shall invoke' rows. I've already tried to apply the filter for 'N's and then union all it with 'Y's, as i described in my last listing. The method has a great disadvantage - indexing stop working if union/union all is used